# how to pass textbox value to crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i want to pass the text box value to crystal report . i have added one parameter named "JoiningDate" in parameters fields and that parameter field i have added in .rpt files {?JoiningDate}. how to add my parameter in the code behind.

```
ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
    crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/ExperienceLetter.rpt"));
    DataSet dsCustomers = GetData("select top 1 * from employees");
    crystalReport.SetDataSource(dsCustomers);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport; 
    string dateValue = txtJoiningDate.Text;
    crystalReport.SetParameterValue("@JoiningDate", dateValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to show text value , i sagest use the code below .

```
TextObject txtObj = (TextObject)crystalReport.ReportDefinition.Sections["GroupHeaderSection1"].ReportObjects["Text10"];
```

but for some logic or calculations use model binding ..
 Visit: http://tektutorialshub.com/how-to-create-crystal-report-using-visual-studio/

Comment: giving me error - Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

Answer (score 1):

```
    TextObject text = (TextObject)cr.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section3"].ReportObjects["Text1"];
text.Text = textBox1.Text;
```

[here](http://www.csharp-tutorials1.blogspot.com/2016/03/pass-textbox-value-to-crystal-report-in.html) is simple example explaining it.